# TCI ( Tag control information ) use VLAN

Tags: vlan, lan, switching, trunk

I have simple VLAN network diagram .

I want to show how the TCI field can be used to have a VLAN number policy for this diagram.

How do I do this?

[image]

Comment: The diagram isn't about VLANs, and I really don't understand the question. Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: I want to get better understand about tci and its usage with VLAN.

Comment: Sorry for unclear problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except for frames in the native VLAN, when a switch puts a frame on a trunk, it inserts a VLAN tag into the frame.

The TCI is 16 bits, which increases the maximum frame size from 1518 bytes to 1522 bytes. The first four bits basically serve the purpose of layer-2 QoS. Three bits are for the priority, and one bit is for indicating whether or not the frame is eligible to be dropped if there is congestion, although in extreme congestion, it can be dropped, anyway.

The last 12 bits of the TCI are the VLAN ID. This gives 4096 different VLAN numbers (0 to 4095), the first and last of which are reserved for special purposes.

A switch, receiving a tagged frame will look at the TCI before stripping it out of the frame and sending it to an access switch port which is configured for the VLAN contained in the VLAN ID of the TCI. It strips the tag out of the frame on access ports because hosts generally don't know what to do with a tagged frame. If a host supports tagged frames, the switch port to the host can be configured as a trunk port instead of an access port.

A VLAN numbering policy is up to the network designer. Typically, VLAN 1 is used for the native VLAN (untagged frames on trunks) because it is the default VLAN for most switches. Using VLAN 1, or even having a native VLAN at all, can open you up to some layer-2 attacks and security risks, but depending on the vendor, switch model, or software version, some switches must use VLAN 1 and/or a native VLAN. Cisco switches will not let you remove VLAN 1, but with modern IOS, you can restrict any VLAN, including VLAN 1, from a trunk, and you don't need to have a native VLAN configured for a trunk.